# Regular Expression for exactly N elements, not less, not more

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to figure out what the regex for finding matches with exactly N occurrences, not less, not more, of a group of characters. It looks like a pretty simple task, but I have not been able to find the proper regex for it.

More specifically, I want a regex that tells whether a given string contains exactly 3 digits - not less, not more.

I thought I would be able to achieve it simply by treating the 3 digits as a group and adding a quantifier of {1} after it, but it does not work.

Alternately, I expected [0-9][0-9][0-9] to work as well, but again it does not. Both *regexes* return the very same results, for the an input set as
1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345.

Below is a code sample that performs what I tried, as described above.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Regex> regexes = new List<Regex> { new Regex("\\d{3}"), new Regex("[0-9][0-9][0-9]"), new Regex("(\\d{3}){1}") };
        List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345 };

        foreach(Regex regex in regexes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing regex {0}", regex.ToString());
            foreach (int number in numbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", number, regex.IsMatch(number.ToString()) ? "is a match" : "not a match"));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output to the program above is:
[image]

Clearly, only 123 is a match, from all the input values.
What would be the regular expression that treats "123" alone as a match ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of your regular expressions are for 3 digits *anywhere* on the input. You are looking for:

```
new Regex("^\\d{3}$")
```

The `^` matches the beginning of the input, and the `$` matches the end of the input. So this regular expression states, "From the beginning, there must be three digits, then expect the end."

Comment: oh no... argh :) I always forget the beginning/end stuff.

Comment: off course it's not, I forgot to add the "m" (multiline) flag.

Answer (score 3):

You should prefix with `^` to indicate the start of the string and `$` to indicate its end. See http://regexr.com/3be8e for a working example.

Comment: by the way, I just posted today in my blog a link recommending regexr, which is awesome.

Comment: so I just learned that... using the beginning and ending anchors is meaningless - unless you add the multiline flag ?

Comment: @Veverke regexr uses a multiline text box for input, it does not treat each line on it as distinct input as you are doing in C#. Unless you specify multiline with regexr, ^$ matches the beginning and of of the whole block: the beginning of the first line to the end of the last line.

Comment: @unxnut It's not supposed to match that, the string should contain exactly three digits

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking for `n` characters followed by a non-character.  So, if you are looking for digits, you should be looking for `n` digits followed by a non-digit.  Make sure that you precede the regex by a non-digit as well.

Comment: but I do not know - I do not want to know - about what precedes or follows my 3 digits.

Comment: Exactly the point, as long as it is not a digit.  And that is specified by `[^\d]`.  So, your expression will be `[^\d]\d{3}[^\d]`.

Comment: but it does not look good, check it: http://regexr.com/3be8q. It is matching stuff that it is not supposed to (but your regex asks it so).

Comment: This method will only find three digits if they are not the first or last characters in a string. For example, it does not match either of the three-digit numbers in http://regexr.com/3be8t.

Comment: Fix it by: `^[^\d]*\d{3}[^\d]*$`

Comment: Your expression works, so I upvoted, since it is also a solution. Although I think you agree it is not the most simple and elegant.